# Is it mandatory to use GCM service to show push notification?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification

I am developing a Cordova app having a Java backend. I want to know if it's mandatory to use GCM service in order to show a push notification in Android/iOS (in notification tray)?

I am using Apache Kafka, MQTT brokers in my backend. Is it possible to show push notification using these solutions, i.e. using completely self defined solutions?

Using MQTT & other brokers I am able to send realtime data to users but how to show those message as native notification in notification bar is my problem.

Comment: On older phones you can use anything.  On 6.0+, you may have issues with Doze-  the phone turns off network for all but apps that are whitelisted if the screen is off and not plugged in for a period of time, and opens up a window for networking once an hour or so.  GCM is whitelisted.  AN MQTT thread wouldn't be

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will need to use GCM to send push notifications to Android devices. You can even use GCM to send push notifications to iOS devices (GCM makes request to APNS (Apple push notification service) to make it work).

But GCM for iOS isnt trusted much.

You can use any backend to send push notification to your devices. You just need to make a request to GCM/APNS.

This is the [cordova plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) for push notification.

Integrating with GCM is damn easy, but it takes a little effort with APNS.

Most people use third party paid services like Pushwoosh to implement their push backend because its convenient. There is a free alternative OneSignal but it tracks your usage.

Follow this [guide](http://www.mattburkedev.com/ios-and-android-push-notifications-with-pushsharp/) to setup push for APNS. (You can just use the Setup certificate part from this guide, since you are not using C#)

Comment: Also APNS requires you to have port 2195 opened on your firewall for the whole IP address range 17.x.x.x

This may be a problem if you have a very secure production server.

https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT203609

Comment: SOme people use 3rd party services.  Not anywhere near most.

Answer (score 0):

To receive push you need use/implement GCM(and actually FCM, because of GCM deprecation)
To show notification from app it is unnecessary to implement GCM/FCM